# DB2 - Error MCH1210 - Receiver value too small to hold result

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

i'm experiencing the error in subject (MCH1210 - Receiver value too small to hold result.) when I try to do a View export from IBM System iNavigator.
This View contains around 2 millions record.
I tried to do a data export with another View, just with some records (less than 100), and it works properly.

Could you help me how to solve this issue?
Are there any other possible ways to achieve the goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What calculation(s) does you view perform?  Can you show your code, and perhaps the relevant column definitions in your base table(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your current Service Pack to see if you are current.  Check PTFs on the IBM i side to make sure you are current.  Generally speaking, any MCH errors in Navigator are a defect that should be reported to IBM, but the first thing they'll want you to do is get current.

Check the job log (View > Job log) to see what the underlying error is.  The job log might reveal something about the view that sheds light on the situation (like a CAST going to too small a data type).

Comment: You might try creating a table from the view via CREATE TABLE mytable AS (SELECT * FROM myview) WITH DATA.  If there's a problem in the view, that will fail and you might have an easier time tracking down why.

Answer (score -1):

My query was running in iNavigator until I added some commented out hyper links for my own reference.
After removing the comments, it worked again.