# Java SQLException SQL0901 and AS400 MCH1210 errors

Tags: java, db2, db2-400

I'm running a rather large query (~83k results) through my Java Application that is producing the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0901] SQL system error. Cause . . . . . :   An SQL system er
>   ror has occurred.  The current SQL statement cannot be completed successfully.  The error will not prevent other SQL statements from being processed. Previous messages may indicate that there is a problem with the SQL statement and SQL did not correctly diagnose the error. The previous message identifier was MCH1210. Internal error type 3002 has occurred. If precompiling, processing will not continue beyond this statement. Recovery: See the previous messages to determine if there is a problem with the SQL statement. To view the messages, use the DSPJOBLOG command if running interactively, or the WRKJOB command to view the output of a precompile.  An application program receiving this return code may attempt further SQL statements.  Correct any errors and try the request again.

From [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql0901-returned-sql-trace-when-accessing-db2400) page, it appears as though Error SQL0901 means I may have a Driver issue.

Digging into the MCH1210 error, yielded [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403738/db2-error-mch1210-receiver-value-too-small-to-hold-result) so I thought that maybe I would have the same issue, however there are a few differences.

When I attempt to run my query in the System iNavigator, it works just fine. When it runs in my application, I get the above error.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    DWVNDN, DWINVN, DWDTEI, DWRTPE, DWINAM, DWCHKN, DWJCDE
FROM HSDATA4.DWRECAP
WHERE DWDTEI > 20180901 AND (DWRTPE = 2 OR DWRTPE = 3) AND DWINVN IN 
    (SELECT DW.DWINVN 
     FROM HSDATA4.DWRECAP DW
         INNER JOIN HSDATA4.FXVNDCP FX ON DW.DWVNDN = FX.FXVNDN 
     WHERE DW.DWRTPE = 1 AND DW.DWDTEI BETWEEN 20180904 AND 20190904)
ORDER BY DWDTEI ASC, DWVNDN ASC;
```

I should note that when changing the inner query from `SELECT ...` to `SELECT COUNT(*)` to get a tally of records coming back, the returned value is 83314, so the main query is using over 83k parameters.

I was originally going to ignore it because I was getting results, however it appears that some of the results end up getting cut off so I don't know how to proceed.

Also, if you hate the column names in the database...so do I. It wasn't my choice...

Comment: Is the i-series level *current* (most recent PTF) for your version of i ?  The "Internal error type 3002" is worth searching.  You should edit your question to give the exact i version, the driver you are using (its name and version).

Comment: @mao would you be able to point me in the right direction to find that information? I don't know where to look.

Comment: Did you look in the job log of the system job processing the request to see if further details?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the inner join give you everything that you need?

```
SELECT
   DW.DWVNDN, DW.DWINVN, DW.DWDTEI, DW.DWRTPE, DW.DWINAM, DW.DWCHKN, DW.DWJCDE
FROM HSDATA4.DWRECAP DW
   INNER JOIN HSDATA4.FXVNDCP FX ON DW.DWVNDN = FX.FXVNDN 
WHERE DW.DWRTPE = 1 AND DW.DWDTEI BETWEEN 20180904 AND 20190904
   AND DW.DWDTEI > 20180901 AND DW.DWRTPE IN (2,3)
ORDER BY DW.DWDTEI ASC, DW.DWVNDN ASC;
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work at all. We're conflicting the DWRTPE field by having it twice with different values. The idea is that DWRTPE = 1 means it's the original invoice data, while 2 or 3 are adjustments or payments. Ideally we are only pulling Invoice data where the original invoice date is between a date range, and the other two types are after it. Pulling in payments/adjustments on an invoice before the start date would be of no use.

Answer (score 0):

How about an outer join

```
SELECT
   DW2.DWVNDN, DW2.DWINVN, DW2.DWDTEI, DW2.DWRTPE, DW2.DWINAM, DW2.DWCHKN, DW2.DWJCDE
   FROM
      (( HSDATA4.DWRECAP DW INNER JOIN HSDATA4.FXVNDCP FX
         ON DW.DWVNDN = FX.FXVNDN AND DW.DWRTPE = 1
            AND DW.DWDTEI BETWEEN 20180904 AND 20190904)
      LEFT OUTER JOIN HSDATA4.DWRECAP DW2
         ON DW.DWVNDN = DW2.DWVNDN
            AND DW2.DWDTEI > 20180901 AND DW2.DWRTPE in (2,3))
```

The inner join selects the initial invoice type of 1 between your valid date ranges and the left outer join selects matching invoice numbers where there was a modification